# Finding the address of an environment variable with and without GDB

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, gdb

I am trying to do an exploit, which spawns a shell, the shellcode is inside an environment variable and I launch the program or GDB with a clean environment so the variable is at the top.

```
env -i MYVAR=10 gdb ./prog
```

The thing is, inside GDB there are variables called COLUMNS and LINES and removing them
using:

```
unset env COLUMNS
unset env LINES
```

and then printing the env with:

```
x/20s *((char **)environ)
```

Still produces an output where those variables are visible and with the same addresses.
I know I have deleted them because using

```
show env COLUMNS
```

Produces an error stating that the variable is not defined.

How can I show the newly updated environment without those that have been deleted?

My goal is finding the address of MYVAR outside of GDB, but I cannot tamper with the program,
so by replicating the environment inside GDB without the variables set by it I can get the address.

Thank you,
Josh

Answer (score 1):

The environment is the second array of strings that is passed as the third "envp" argument to the `execve()` system call when a process executes a command, the first one being the arguments ("argv").

By convention, those strings are in the `var=value` format.

```
execve("/path/to/cmd", ["cmd", "arg1", "arg2"], ["var1=value1", "var2=value2"])
```

By convention, when executing other commands, often in a child process of theirs, commands pass along the environment strings that they received when they were executed to the command they execute. The `execvp()` function in the C library, itself a wrapper around the `execve()` system call does that by default. In the C library (which commands may or may not be linked against but generally are), the `environ` variable  is populated based on the envp array that was received upon execution. That variable is what is passed as envp in further `execve()`s by `execvp()` / `execlp()` / `system()` / `popen()`... and `putenv()` / `setenv()` / `unsetenv()` update that `environ` array.

`unset env var` in `gdb` just does the equivalent of that `unsetenv()` (possibly even call it), and just means that all the strings starting with `var=` that `gdb` received when it started won't be included in the `envp` array that is passed to the commands that `gdb` will execute from now on.

Once a command is executed, they can do whatever they want with the `envp` array they received (which will be at the bottom of their stack) including populating `environ` the variable like applications using the libc do or like `perl` mapping it to its `%ENV` associative array or shells that typically create a shell variable for most of the env vars whose name is compatible with a shell variable name.